# random-beans initialized bean collection size does not match configured size

Tags: java, spring, testing, random-beans

I am trying to use the random-beans library to create my test beans faster. The dependency used is (https://github.com/benas/random-beans):

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.benas</groupId>
        <artifactId>random-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Beans are:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String  surname;

private Integer age;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Book> books;
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Book {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String title;

private String description;

private Integer pages;
```

This is my test code (limiting collectionsize to 1):

https://github.com/cristianprofile/create-test-random-beans/blob/master/src/test/java/com/cromero/randombeaninstantationtesting/RandomBeanInstantationTestingApplicationTests.java#L41

```
 EnhancedRandom random = EnhancedRandomBuilder.aNewEnhancedRandomBuilder()
            .charset(forName("UTF-8"))
            .stringLengthRange(5, 50)
            .collectionSizeRange(1, 1)
            .scanClasspathForConcreteTypes(true)
            .overrideDefaultInitialization(false)
            .build();
    User user = random.random(User.class);

    assertThat(user.getBooks()).hasSize(1);
```

My test fail in this assert:

```
  assertThat(user.getBooks()).hasSize(1);
```

Why books size is not the same as I have configured with my random object. Why is that?

Comment: I added an answer, if it helped, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the static method `random` on the non-static `random` instance, you should call the `nextObject` method instead:

```
User user = random.nextObject(User.class);
```

Since the method `EnhancedRandom.random` is static, it takes only default configuration options and not the ones that are set on `EnhancedRandom` instances.

Hope this helps.